# Deleting parts of a frame using grid_forget Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pack, ttk

I have used the following code to delete a section of my frame (wish to delete the number of boxes currently showing - this can vary):

```
for i in xrange(self.number_boxes):

    self.box[i].grid_remove()
    self.choice_title.grid_remove()
```

I however end up with the following:

[image: Table]

What am I doing wrong to be stuck with the last part of the main window staying there?!

I have the root window, then a main window, 'win1' in which a frame 'frame_table' holds all the table. The background is set to black.

UPDATE: Corresponds to changing options in OptionMenu:

Rather than having created seperate frames I have just created a set of entry boxes in the current frame 'frame_table'. When a 'list' option is chosen, the user inputs the amount of boxes to be created. With the other option it's always 2 boxes which are created. With the 'fixed' value, all boxes need to be deleted as no additional boxes are required.

Therefore, if one goes from 'list' to 'other option in menu (not fixed)', the boxes from the 'list' option need to be deleted prior to creating the new boxes.

Comment: So you want **All** of those widgets to go away?  It's unclear what is wrong here.  Could you describe that a little more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiom:

```
for i in xrange(self.number_boxes):

    self.box[i].grid_remove()
    self.choice_title.grid_remove()
```

should rarely be necessary in python.  Perhaps you aren't seeing your boxes removed because your `self.number_boxes` is incorrect (maybe you forgot to update it somewhere).  A better way to do it is:

```
for box in self.boxes:
    box.grid_remove()
else:
    self.choice_title.grid_remove()
```

This may (or may not) solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you. This however only deletes the final box.

Comment: @user2063 -- See my answer to your other question.  your `boxes` list isn't what you think it is ;).

Comment: Have figured this one out, thanks for posting the comment on this question as well!